# Is there a way to make a button that will send you to different UIViews in Swift UI

Tags: swift, swiftui

Basically I need to make a button with nested if/else statements to send a user to different UIviews depending on the choice from a picker.
I want to link to UIViews in the If statements, but I can't find out how to do so.
I have tried a navigation view (probably incorrectly) and anything I google is not helpful

---

```
Button(action: {
      if (self.notations[self.notation]) == "Select" {

       } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Select" {

       } else if (self.notations[self.notation]) == "Note Names" {
              if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Piano" {

              } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Guitar" {

              } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Saxophone" {

              } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Bass" {

              }
       } else if (self.notations[self.notation]) == "Treble Clef" {
              if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Piano" {

              } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Guitar" {

              } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Saxophone" {

              } else {

              }
       } else if (self.notations[self.notation]) == "Bass Clef" {
              if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Piano" {

              } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Bass" {

              } else {

              }
       } else if (self.notations[self.notation]) == "TAB" {
              if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Guitar" {

              } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Bass" {

              } else {

              }
       } else if (self.notations[self.notation]) == "Piano" {
              if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Guitar" {

              } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Saxophone" {

              } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Bass" {

               } else {

               }
       } else if (self.notations[self.notation]) == "Guitar" {
               if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Saxophone" {

               } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Piano" {

               } else {

               }
       }
}) ***
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try the following code and explain it with your own goals.

```
            struct WebLinkView: View {

                @State private var notations: [String] = ["Select", "Note Names","Treble Clef", "Bass Clef", "Tab", "Piano","Guitar"];
                @State private var instruments: [String] = ["Select", "Piano","Guitar", "Saxophone", "Bass", "Bass","Guitar"];
                @State private var  notation: Int = 0
                @State private var instrument: Int = 0
                @State private var  notation_instrument: String?


                var body: some View {


                    func target<T> (_ s: T)-> NavigationLink<Text,  T> {
                       return  NavigationLink<Text, T>("New Link: " + self.notations[self.notation] + "__" + self.instruments[self.instrument], destination: s, tag: self.notations[self.notation] + self.instruments[self.instrument], selection: $notation_instrument)


                    }

                     let nextPage = target(Text("\(self.notations[self.notation]): \(self.instruments[self.instrument])"))

                     let ExamplePage1 = target(Group{VStack{Text("11")
                                   Text("Test Page")
                           Image(systemName: "house")
                           Image(systemName: "camera")
                        }})

                      let ExamplePage2 = target( Image(systemName: "heart.fill"))

                return    NavigationView{

                    Group{
                        VStack{
                    Picker(selection:self.$notation , label: Text("notation")) {
                        ForEach(0..<(notations.count)){ Text(self.notations[$0]).tag($0)  }
                    }

                    Picker(selection:self.$instrument , label: Text("instrument")){
                        ForEach(0..<(instruments.count)){ Text(self.instruments[$0]).tag($0)  }
                           }


                                    if (self.notations[self.notation]) == "Select" {
                   nextPage
                                      } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Select" {
                   nextPage
                                      } else if (self.notations[self.notation]) == "Note Names" {
                                          if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Piano" {
                   ExamplePage1
                                          } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Guitar" {
                   ExamplePage1
                                          } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Saxophone" {
                   ExamplePage2
                                          } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Bass" {
                   nextPage
                                          }
                                      } else if (self.notations[self.notation]) == "Treble Clef" {
                                          if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Piano" {
                   nextPage
                                          } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Guitar" {
                   nextPage
                                          } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Saxophone" {
                   nextPage
                                          } else {
                   nextPage
                                          }
                                      } else if (self.notations[self.notation]) == "Bass Clef" {
                                          if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Piano" {
                   nextPage
                                          } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Bass" {
                   nextPage
                                          } else {
                   nextPage
                                          }
                                      } else if (self.notations[self.notation]) == "TAB" {
                                          if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Guitar" {
                   nextPage
                                          } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Bass" {
                   nextPage
                                          } else {
                   nextPage
                                          }
                                      } else if (self.notations[self.notation]) == "Piano" {
                                          if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Guitar" {
                   nextPage
                                          } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Saxophone" {
                   nextPage
                                          } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Bass" {
                   nextPage
                                          } else {
                   nextPage
                                          }
                                      } else if (self.notations[self.notation]) == "Guitar" {
                                          if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Saxophone" {
                   nextPage
                                          } else if (self.instruments[self.instrument]) == "Piano" {
                   nextPage
                                          } else {
                   nextPage
                                          }
                                      }
                       }

                    }
                    }
                    }
                }
```